# How to update an array in Mongoose JS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Currently, I'm trying to create a Discord bot that will save a to-do list in a database. To do so, I wanted to use an array that contains any items the person adds by typing *!listadd (something)* that will then be stored in a MongoDB database. However, while this seems to work for Strings, I cannot seem to change an array at all using this method.

`await list.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id},{$push:{todoList: msg}, itemToAdd:msg},{upsert : true})`

This line above is what I'm using to update the list. While the change to **itemToAdd** is reflected perfectly in the database, nothing is pushed to **todoList**. I can't even seem to update **todoList** at all past setting what the default value is in the schema. (Like, if I put `{todoList:['one','two']}` as the update object, it still won't do anything)

I've tried using the *.updateOne()* method and, again, it works fine for **itemToAdd**, but nothing happens to **todoList**. I've also tried using the *.markModified()* method and I've either used it wrong or it isn't working here because, still, nothing changes in the database.

Full Code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  todolist : [String],
  _id: {
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  itemToAdd:{
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  indexOfItemToRemove:{
    type: Number,
    required: false
  }
  
});

const list = mongoose.model('list', todoSchema);

module.exports = async (client) => {
  client.on('message', async (message) => {
    const { author } = message;
    const { id } = author;
    const { bot } = author;
    if (!bot){
    console.log('AUTHOR:', author);
    if (message.content.includes('!listadd ')){
      const msg = message.content.substring(9)
        await list.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id},{$push:{todoList: msg}, itemToAdd:msg},{upsert : true})
      message.reply('Entry Added!')
  }
    if (message.content.includes('!listget')){
      let doc = await list.findOne({_id:id})
      message.reply(doc.itemToAdd)
    }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: The field in the schema is `todolist`, but your update has `todoList`.

Comment: I feel so silly, thank you so much.